# mysql group_concat showing all dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

profile  `userid, fname,lname`

schedule: `userid, date, start_time, end_time`

Here is my query .

> select *, group_CONCAT(distinct(date),'_',start_time,'_',end_time)
>   as dateformat FROM profile, schedule WHERE profile.userid =
>   schedule.pid

This returns all dates from the table.  But what I am trying to do is return only certain days like:

```
date >= DATE(NOW()) and date <= date(now() + 2 day)
```

So today tomorrow and the day after.

No matter what I try it just returns all dates in the schedule database.  I need this to return 2 rows userid 5 has 1 row in profile but 5 rows in schedule and userid 6 has 1 row in profile and 2 rows in schedule the query works fine its just returning all dates and not the dates within the

```
"date >= DATE(NOW()) and date <= date(now() + 2 day)"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try GROUP BY?

like `WHERE profile.userid = schedule.pid GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 0):

select profile.userid,schedule.userid, group_CONCAT(distinct(date),'_',start_time,'_',end_time) as dateformat FROM profile, schedule WHERE profile.userid = schedule.userid and date >= DATE(NOW()) and date <= date(now() + interval 2 day);

That did it for now!! Now I can use the dateformat variable in php to parse out my results.

kanishka panamaldeniya - thanks for your suggestion!